# total number of duplicates in oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, count, duplicates

I have a table like below

```
SUBJECT Years MARKS
AB      1       20
AB      1       25
AC      1       20
AC      1       30
AC      1       40
AD      1       20
```

I only need count of duplicates (subject||Year), expected answer is 2
and not

```
AB1 -- 2
AC1 -- 3
```

Comment: what means "expected answer is 2"? what is the result expected?

Comment: What you have tried ?? you want a sql command ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count duplicates records in Mysql table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528644/count-duplicates-records-in-mysql-table)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be one more query on top of the duplicates query...

```
select subject, year, count(*)
  from table1
  group by subject, year
  having count(*) > 1
```

will give you all the results with counts. Another count over this..

```
select count(*)
  from (
select subject, year, count(*)
  from table1
  group by subject, year
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

should give you the number of records which have one or more duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
select subject,years, count(*)
from table
group by subject,years
having count (*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an inline view over the query you used to get your example (AB1, AC1) like this:

```
select count (*) from (select subject, years from t group by subject, years having count (*) > 1)
```