# Count duplicates records in Mysql table?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have table with, folowing structure.

tbl

```
id   name  
1    AAA
2    BBB
3    BBB
4    BBB
5    AAA
6    CCC

select count(name) c from tbl
group by name having c >1
```

The query returning this result:

```
AAA(2)  duplicate
BBB(3)  duplicate
CCC(1)  not duplicate
```

The names who are duplicates as AAA and BBB. The final result, who I want is count of this duplicate records.

Result should be like this:
     Total duplicate products (**2**)

Comment: Isn't number of rows in result of your query is the number of duplicate records in table???

Comment: Yes! The result is the number of duplicate records in table.

Comment: So what's the question here now? You want to count number of duplicates and now you have it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The approach is to have a nested query that has one line per duplicate, and an outer query returning just the count of the results of the inner query.

```
SELECT count(*) AS duplicate_count
FROM (
 SELECT name FROM tbl
 GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
) AS t
```

Comment: @Awesome_girl I don't understand your example, a~d is 4, where does the 5 come from ?

Answer (score 17):

Use IF statement to get your desired output:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS times, IF (COUNT(*)>1,"duplicated", "not duplicated") AS duplicated FROM <MY_TABLE> GROUP BY name
```

Output:

```
AAA 2 duplicated
BBB 3 duplicated
CCC 1 not duplicated
```

Comment: Then How do we take sum of within query? 2+3+1 ??

Answer (score 13):

**For List:**

```
SELECT COUNT(`name`) AS adet, name
FROM  `tbl` WHERE `status`=1 GROUP BY `name`
ORDER BY `adet`  DESC
```

### [image: Table View]

**For Total Count:**

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(name) AS cou FROM tbl GROUP BY name HAVING cou>1 ) AS virtual_tbl
```

// Total: 5

Comment: the question is asking for a total number of duplicates, not a list

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM (SELECT COUNT(name) AS cou FROM tbl GROUP BY name HAVING cou>1 ) AS virtual_tbl 

@Awesome_girl

Answer (score 12):

why not just wrap this in a sub-query:

```
SELECT Count(*) TotalDups
FROM
(
    select Name, Count(*)
    from yourTable
    group by name
    having Count(*) > 1
) x
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba202/1)

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer **counts the number of rows that have duplicates**, not the **amount of duplicates**. If you want to count the **actual number of duplicates**, use this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(rows) - count(1), 0) as dupes FROM(

    SELECT COUNT(1) as rows
    FROM `yourtable`
    GROUP BY `name`
    HAVING rows > 1

) x
```

What this does is total the duplicates in the group by, but then subtracts the amount of records that have duplicates. The reason is the group by total is not all duplicates, one record of each of those groupings is the unique row.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29639a/3

Comment: The question asks for the number of duplicates (2) not the total number of rows in the duplicates (5).

Answer (score 0):

SQL code is:

```
SELECT VERSION_ID, PROJECT_ID, VERSION_NO, COUNT(VERSION_NO) AS dup_cnt
FROM MOVEMENTS
GROUP BY VERSION_NO
HAVING (dup_cnt > 1 && PROJECT_ID = 11660)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this query for my own table in PHP, but it only gives me one result whereas I'd like to the amount of duplicate per username, is that possible?

```
SELECT count(*) AS duplicate_count
FROM (
 SELECT username FROM login_history
 GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(time) > 1
) AS t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query:

```
select user_name, count(*) 
from users 
group by user_name 
having count(user_name) > 1
```

This will return:

| user_name | count |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 5 |
| xyz | 3 |