# How do I count duplicate entries into MYSQL database and display the results using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in a SQL database and I want to compare columns from them, then when there are more than 1 duplicate entries I want to count them and display with PHP and create a list of only the pageCatagorys that are duplicates

My two Tables look like this:

Table: pageCatagorys

```
ID | catagory
1  | Home
2  | Test 1
3  | Other Services
```

Table: pages

```
ID | pageName | pageCatagory   | pageURL
1  | Test 1   | Test 1         | test-1
2  | Test 2   | Test 1         | test-2
3  | Test 3   | Home           | test-3
4  | Test 4   | Other Services | test-4
```

When I run the query `$pagecount = mysql_query("SELECT pageCatagory, COUNT(*) FROM pages GROUP BY pageCatagory HAVING COUNT(*) > 1");` in phpMyAdmin i get the below result table:

```
pageCatagory     | COUNT(*)
Test 1           |    2
```

However its always hitting the else rule in my code below.

```
<?php
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT catagory FROM pageCatagorys");

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
                    $pagecount = mysql_query("SELECT pageCatagory, COUNT(*) FROM pages GROUP BY pageCatagory HAVING COUNT(*) > 1");
                        if($pagecount > 1){
                        ?>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $row["catagory"] ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <?php   $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT pageName, pageURL FROM pageURL"); 
                            while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)) { ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $row["pageName"] ?>"><?php echo $row["pageName"] ?></a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                <?php  }  else { ?> 
                <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row["catagory"] ?></a></li>
   <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: already answered here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528644/count-duplicates-records-in-mysql-table)

Comment: You are not assigning `$pagecount`.  This is strictly a php issue . . . and you should start using mysqli_.

Comment: `$pagecount` is a resource, fetch it

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I dunno about the kittens, @RiggsFolly, but I do know that every time somebody uses the `mysql_` interface, a cybercriminal pwns a website somewhere in the world.