# Returning the total number of rows with value that show up in the table at least twice

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show the total number of rows from a table that have a certain row value at least twice. So basically duplicates. I WHERE and HAVING but nothing works as it returns invalid use of group function message. Below one of the examples of my queries.

```
SELECT      
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    table 
WHERE
    COUNT(column) > 1;
```

Probably I should do some nested query but don't know how yet. What query shall I use to receive the correct result?

Comment: Try looking up how to do nested queries? You seem to be on the right track...

Comment: Hi @Michal_SI do u get your expected results?

Answer (score 0):

To find duplicate rows -

```sql
SELECT column, COUNT(column)  
FROM table_name  
GROUP BY column  
HAVING COUNT(column) > 1;
```

To get count of duplicates -

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
 SELECT column FROM table_name
 GROUP BY column HAVING COUNT(column) > 1
) AS t
```

Comment: This counts the number of duplicates, it doesn't count the number of rows containing those duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery that gets the row counts for all the duplicates rows. Then sum that in the main query.

```
SELECT SUM(t.rowcount)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount
    FROM table
    GROUP BY column
    HAVING rowcount > 1)
) AS t
```

Comment: I see that you reopened this question. Please explain why it is not a duplicate of [Count duplicates records in Mysql table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528644/count-duplicates-records-in-mysql-table) The SQL in your answer is almost identical to that in the accepted answer of the "duplicate" question.

Comment: It's the difference between `COUNT(*)` and `SUM(rowcount)`. The other question counts each duplicate just once, this counts the total number of rows that have the duplicate values.

Comment: In the other question, the answer is `2`. With my code the result will be `5`.